# MonoTouch Error: "The Apple iPhone SDK not installed" after upgrade to iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've upgraded iOS 5.0.1 to 5.1 and I'm using MonoTouch 5.2.5 and MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5. When I created a sample applcation in MonoDevelop, it shows the error "The apple iphone sdk not installed".

How do I get MonoTouch to work with iOS 5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you only update your device(s) to iOS 5.1 ? or

Did you install the new Xcode **4.3.1** from the AppStore ?

That where the iOS 5.1 SDK is available and [MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/17/update-on-xcode-4-3-support/) should pick it up automatically.

From **MonoDevelop** menu, select **About Mono Develop** item, select the **Version Info** tab and look if anything is listed as missing (or simply looks wrong). You can edit your question to include this information (up to the **Loaded Assemblies** section).

Comment: i've updated my device.i'm using only evaluation version of mono. Installed xcode 4.3.1 from AppStore. In monoDevelop menu, in version info, it's showing Apple Developer tools (Not Found). is this the reason for the problem. Where have to find the developer tools?

Comment: problem gets solved.I installed the xcode in a different location. Now  monotouch gave no error.

Comment: You could also set MonoDevelop's SDK preferences to an alternative path (if you did not install Xcode in the default directory).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem:

set the apple SDK in MonoDevelop to the correct installed version of XCode. This wil fix this issue. I did not find this answer anywhere, but this did the trick for me!