# Error Apple IPhone SDK not installed

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, xamarin.ios

I have installed MacOSX 10.7.4, XCODE 4.3.3, Monotouch 5.2.12(Evaluation)
I try to build the samples "HelloWorld_IPhone" and I received error: "Apple IPhone SDK not installed".
How can I solve this error?
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736333/monotouch-error-the-apple-iphone-sdk-not-installed-after-upgrade-to-ios-5-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, you have to download and Install the Apple Iphone SDK

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/01/25/iphone-dev-101-downloading-and-install-the-iphone-sdk/

Comment: No with the new XCode the SDK path has been changed, as the topic started already mentioned he has Xcode 4.3.3 in stalled.